# Book recommendation request on Spectral theory

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, book-recommendation, spectral-theory

Can someone please recommend to me a text that deals on spectral theory from the scratch covering the parts of a spectrum (approximate, point and compression) explicitly. Theorems and properties. Thank you.

Comment: Functional Analysis by Reed and Simon is quite good

Comment: @Mariah I am on the book now. There is nothing on parts of a spectrum like approximate point spectrum, etc

Comment: Kreyszig - "Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications" Chapter 7

Comment: Taylor - "Introduction to Functional Analysis" Chapter 5